# R: Errors encountered during "loops": x Input `name` can't be recycled to size 100

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, plotly, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I made an earlier post ([R: Using "microbenchmark" and ggplot2 to plot runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458335/r-using-microbenchmark-and-ggplot2-to-plot-runtimes)) where I am learning how to use loops and functions to iterate procedures (7 procedures) in R for sample sizes. Once this is done, I want to produce a plot.

Based on the previous answer, I tried to write a few of these loops in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rtsne)
library(cluster)
library(dbscan)
library(plotly)
library(microbenchmark)

#simulate data

var_1 <- rnorm(1000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(1000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
var_4 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )

#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4,ID=1:1000)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
f$var_4 = as.factor(f$var_4)

# configure run sizes
sizes <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)

# Procedure 1: :
proc1 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("gower_dist_",size), daisy(f[1:size,-5],
                        metric = "gower"),envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
    assign(paste0("gower_mat_",size),as.matrix(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv)),
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
}     

proc1List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc1(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})

proc1summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc1List))

#procedure2


proc2 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("lof_",size), lof(gower_dist, k=3),envir = .GlobalEnv)}

proc2List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc2(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})


proc2summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc2List))


#procedure3


proc3 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("lof_",size), lof(gower_dist, k=5),envir = .GlobalEnv)}

proc3List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc3(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})


proc3summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc3List))

#procedure4

proc4 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("tsne_obj_",size),Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE),envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
    assign(paste0("tsne_data_",size),tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(
           name = f$ID) ,envir = .GlobalEnv)}


proc4List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc4(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})


proc4summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc4List))


#procedure5

proc5 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("tsne_obj_",size),Rtsne(gower_dist, perplexity = 10,  is_distance = TRUE),envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
    assign(paste0("tsne_data_",size),tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(
           name = f$ID) ,envir = .GlobalEnv)}


proc5List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc5(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})


proc5summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc5List))


#procedure6

proc6 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("plot_",size),ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) + geom_point(aes()),envir = .GlobalEnv)}
        

proc6List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc6(x))
        b$obs <- x
        b
})


proc6summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc6List))

#procedure 7

proc7 <- function(size) {

assign(paste0 ("tsne_obj_", size),  Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE), envir = .GlobalEnv)

assign(paste0 ("tsne_data_", size),  tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
  mutate(
    name = f$ID, 
    lof=lof,
    var1=f$var_1,
    var2=f$var_2,
    var3=f$var_3
    ), envir = .GlobalEnv)

assign(paste0 ("p1_", size),  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, size=lof, key=name, var1=var1, 
  var2=var2, var3=var3), data = tsne_data) + 
  geom_point(shape=1, col="red") + theme_minimal(), envir = .GlobalEnv)


assign(paste0 ("plotly_", size),  
ggplotly(p1, tooltip = c("lof", "name", "var1", "var2", "var3")
 ), envir = .GlobalEnv)


}


proc7List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc7(x))
    b$obs <- x
    b
})



proc7summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc7List))


do.call(rbind,list(proc1summary,proc2summary,proc3summary, proc4summary, proc5summary, proc6summary, proc7summary)) %>% 
    group_by(expr,obs) %>%
    summarise(.,time_ms = mean(time) * .000001) -> proc_time 



ggplot(proc_time,aes(obs,time_ms,group = expr)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = expr),color = "grey80") + 
    geom_point(aes(color = expr))
```

However, for some of these procedures, when I call them though a list, I keep getting an error:

```
proc4List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
     b <- microbenchmark(proc4(x))
     b$obs <- x
     b
 })

 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `name`.
x Input `name` can't be recycled to size 100.
i Input `name` is `f$ID`.
i Input `name` must be size 100 or 1, not 1000.
```

I tried reading other stackoverflow posts ([Input `typ` can't be recycled to size in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795905/input-typ-cant-be-recycled-to-size-in-r)), but I could not understand why this "recycling error" keeps showing up. Is it because "size = 100" is too small? Is it because some of the variables have been named improperly?

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: this error is from `dplyr::mutate` and it's when you're trying to add a column to a tibble but the size of the new column is incompatible. the tibble you're adding the column "name" to has 100 rows, but the vector you're assigning to "name" (f$ID) has 1000 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make procedures 4 - 7 work we needed to make the adjustments listed in the conclusions section of [Using microbenchmark and ggplot2 to plot runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458335/r-using-microbenchmark-and-ggplot2-to-plot-runtimes/65459229#65459229):

1. Wrap the original procedure in a function that we can use as the unit of analysis for `microbenchmark()`, and include a `size` argument
2. Modify the procedure to use `size` as a variable where necessary
3. Modify the procedure to access objects from previous steps, based on the `size` argument
4. Modify the procedure to write its outputs with `assign()` and `size` if these are needed for subsequent procedure steps

The modified code looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rtsne)
library(cluster)
library(dbscan)
library(plotly)
library(microbenchmark)

#simulate data

var_1 <- rnorm(1000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(1000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
var_4 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4,ID=1:1000)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
f$var_4 = as.factor(f$var_4)

# configure run sizes
sizes <- c(10,50,100,200,500,1000)

# configure # of benchmark runs
time_ct <- 10

# Procedure 1: :
proc1 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("gower_dist_",size), daisy(f[1:size,-5],
                        metric = "gower"),envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
    assign(paste0("gower_mat_",size),as.matrix(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv)),
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
        
}     

proc1List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
        b <- microbenchmark(proc1(x),times=time_ct)
        b$obs <- x
        b
})
proc1summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc1List))

#Procedure 2

proc2 <- function(size){
        lof <- lof(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv), k=3)
}
proc2List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc2(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})
proc2summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc2List))

#Procedure 3

proc3 <- function(size){
    assign(paste0("lof_",size),lof(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv), k=5),
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
proc3List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc3(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})
proc3summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc3List))

proc4 <- function(size){
    tsne_obj <- Rtsne(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv),  
                      perplexity = min(30,(size-1)/3),
                      is_distance = TRUE)
    tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
        mutate(
            name = 1:size)
}

proc4List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc4(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})

proc4summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc4List))

proc5 <- function(size){
    tsne_obj <- Rtsne(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv),  
                      perplexity = min(10,(size-1)/3),
                      is_distance = TRUE)
    tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
        mutate(
            name = 1:size)
    assign(paste0("tsne_data_",size),tsne_data,envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

proc5List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc5(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})

proc5summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc5List))

proc6 <- function(size){
    plot = ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = get(paste0("tsne_data_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv)) + geom_point(aes())
    
}

proc6List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc6(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})

proc6summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc6List))

proc7 <- function(size){
    tsne_obj <- Rtsne(get(paste0("gower_dist_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv),  
                      perplexity = min(30,(size-1)/3),
                      is_distance = TRUE)
    
    tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
        mutate(
            name = 1:size, 
            lof=get(paste0("lof_",size),envir = .GlobalEnv),
            var1=f$var_1[1:size],
            var2=f$var_2[1:size],
            var3=f$var_3[1:size]
        )
    
    p1 <- ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, size=lof, key=name, var1=var1, 
                     var2=var2, var3=var3), data = tsne_data) + 
        geom_point(shape=1, col="red")+
        theme_minimal()
    
    ggplotly(p1, tooltip = c("lof", "name", "var1", "var2", "var3"))
    
    
}

proc7List <- lapply(sizes,function(x){
    b <- microbenchmark(proc7(x),times=time_ct)
    b$obs <- x
    b
})

proc7summary <- do.call(rbind,(proc7List))

do.call(rbind,list(proc1summary,proc2summary,proc3summary,proc4summary,proc5summary,
                   proc6summary,proc7summary)) %>% 
    group_by(expr,obs) %>%
    summarise(.,time_ms = mean(time) * .000001) -> proc_time 

head(proc_time)

ggplot(proc_time,aes(obs,time_ms,group = expr)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = expr),color = "grey80") + 
    geom_point(aes(color = expr))
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Notes

Since some of these procedures take a long time to run (relatively speaking), we reduced the number of iterations in `microbenchmark()` from the default of 100 to 10, which is more than sufficient to demonstrate that the code works as intended. Since this was set as a parameter at the top of the code, one can increase this number to increase the number of times each benchmark is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It is very kind of you. I am learning more about different types of "times" that are measured by the computer. Just using basic logic, it seems to me that there are two general types of time : the time corresponding to the mathematical complexity of the operations AND the time taken by your personal computer to execute the operations. In the answer you have provided, (using the "microbenchmark" command), does the time recorded on the graph correspond to the "mathematical complexity" (i.e. the processing time)?

Comment: I am looking at this link over here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/5-ways-to-measure-running-time-of-r-code/ ... in part 1) it seem to show how to calculate the "system time"  (time taken by your personal computer to execute the commands) using the Sys.time() function. Is this correct? I am thinking of modifying your code so that the Sys.time() will be recorded, corresponding to the time taken by your personal computer to execute the same commands.

Comment: @stats555 - you're welcome. Yes, there are multiple types of time tracked within R. Here is an example of the use of system time to [estimate the runtime of an R script](https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/07/01/estimating-R-script-runtime.html).

Comment: Thank you! Suppose you have a very large dataset and a very computational expensive procedure. Is there a way to "estimate the expected time" required to run the procedure?

Comment: @stats555 - unfortunately one has to figure out the right model to estimate the runtime, like I did in [estimate the runtime of an R script](https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/07/01/estimating-R-script-runtime.html).  The key thing is figuring out whether the right model is linear, geometric, or exponential. In the case of the procedure related to my article, the right model was a quadratic model.